# jQuery Mobile 1.4 Nested Popups

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Using JQM 1.4, I no longer can open a new popup from another popup.

```
<a href="#popupBasic" data-rel="popup" 
 class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline" 
data-transition="pop">Basic Popup</a>

<div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic">
   <p>This is a completely basic popup, no options set.</p>
   <a href="#popupBasicAnother" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline" data-transition="pop">Another Popup</a> 
</div>

<div data-role="popup" id="popupBasicAnother">
  <p>Another Popup</p>
</div>
```

This was working fine in 1.3 version.
Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comes from a change in the way links clicked inside a popup widget are handled. In jQuery Mobile 1.3, the currently active popup was forcibly closed so the new one could be opened. This is no longer the case in jQuery Mobile 1.4.

To restore the previous behavior, you can patch `$.mobile.popup.handleLink()` in a [mobileinit](http://api.jquerymobile.com/mobileinit/) handler:

```
$(document).on("mobileinit", function() {
    var originalHandleLink = $.mobile.popup.handleLink;
    $.mobile.popup.handleLink = function(link) {
        var activePopup = $.mobile.popup.active,
            path = $.mobile.path;
        if (activePopup) {
            var popup = $(path.hashToSelector(
                path.parseUrl(link.attr("href")).hash)).first();
            if (popup.length > 0 && popup.data("mobile-popup")) {
                activePopup._close(true);
            }
        }
        originalHandleLink.apply(this, arguments);
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, I will give it a try, but I think JQM team need to ensure they don't break things in the upgrades. It makes it very challenging to upgrade the thousands of applications there are built by previous versions.