# jQuery Mobile 1.4 nested popups - unable to make suggested answer work

Tags: jquery-mobile, popup

I'm unable to post a comment on this question, for some reason:

[jQuery Mobile 1.4 Nested Popups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21679412/jquery-mobile-1-4-nested-popups)

I've tried the accepted answer, with no success. My html is:

```
<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <button id="showpopup1">Show popup 1</button>
    <div id="popup1" data-role="popup">
        <h1>Popup 1</h1>
        <button id="showpopup2">Show popup 2</button>
        <a href="#" data-rel="back">Close</a>
    </div>
    <div id="popup2" data-role="popup">
        <h1>Popup 2</h1>
        <a href="#" data-rel="back">Close</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

and code (using the suggested solution):

```
$(document).on("mobileinit", function() {
    var originalHandleLink = $.mobile.popup.handleLink;
    $.mobile.popup.handleLink = function(link) {
        var activePopup = $.mobile.popup.active,
            path = $.mobile.path;
        if (activePopup) {
            var popup = $(path.hashToSelector(
                path.parseUrl(link.attr("href")).hash)).first();
            if (popup.length > 0 && popup.data("mobile-popup")) {
                activePopup._close(true);
            }
        }
        originalHandleLink.apply(this, arguments);
    };
});

$('#showpopup1').click(function() {
    $('#popup1').popup('open');
});

$('#showpopup2').click(function() {
    $('#popup2').popup('open');
});
```

Which is at this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/davidxn/2rxyC/

Comment: `mobileinit` should be placed after jQuery-core and before jQuery-Mobile in head http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/ZeD5K/. use `a` instead of `button` with `href="popID` and `data-rel=popup`.

Comment: You can also use the third part plugin simpledialog2 to get chained popups: http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/05/16/chained-popups-with-simpledialog2/

Comment: Omar: never mind; that's not going to be a solution for me, as I need the first popup to remain open, or at least re-open in the state it was, after the second popup is closed.
@ezanker: It looks like I'm going to need to do something like that. It's a shame JQM can't do this out of the box.